# How to handle Mixpanel's alias functionality if all users are signed up?

Tags: analytics, ethereum, mixpanel

I'm building an app on Ethereum so all of my users are "signed up" by default because they have a wallet. User ids look like this: 0x5a0b54D5dC17E0AADc386d2db43a0A0d3e029C4c.

Do I only need to call `identify`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely ditch `alias` if you expect all of your users to be signed up. See this article from the Mixpanel documentation:

[Identity Management: Best Practices](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004497803)

> If you’re implementing Mixpanel on a site with users who have already signed up, you do not need call alias on those users.
>
> The primary purpose of calling mixpanel.alias() is to connect a user’s anonymous events from before a signup (or other identification) event with the post-signup activity on your site or in your app.